# Get results from last executed mysqli query in php and use the results in another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have some AJAX/PHP/SQL stuff happening at the moment.

On one page, you select people you want to put into the database (with checkboxes)
jQuery collects the values assigned to the checkbox and stores it in an array. Then I use AJAX to to send the array to a PHP file.

In the PHP file, I want to use that array to insert the value into a table. Which works great.

Once the query is executed, I want to be able to grab the info stored, specifically the ID that is generated to use in another query. I just don't know how to call the last executed query and grab the ID value. This is what I have so far in my PHP file:

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['activitiesArray'];
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO Groups (leader_ID) VALUES (".$myArray[0].")");
printf("%s\n", mysqli_info($conn)); //debugging, see if I can pull out anything.
```

**note - This code is very basic. I just want functionality to work before making it dynamic**

In the Groups table there are 2 columns, leader_ID and gp_ID (which auto increments). I want to use the last executed query to find out what the value of that gp_ID is so I can use it to update another table. I don't know if this is at all possible. Any insight would be fantastic, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`mysqli_insert_id($conn)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the auto-increment ID created by the last `INSERT` query on the connection.

Comment: thanks heaps. Couldn't remember for the love of me what it was called until now. Thank you again!

Comment: Couldn't you just read through the list of mysqli methods in the documentation? It's two lines below the one you tried.